# Why is the new random library better than std::rand()?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

So I saw a talk called [rand() Considered Harmful](https://youtu.be/LDPMpc-ENqY) and it advocated for using the engine-distribution paradigm of random number generation over the simple `std::rand()` plus modulus paradigm.

However, I wanted to see the failings of `std::rand()` firsthand so I did a quick experiment:

1. Basically, I wrote 2 functions `getRandNum_Old()` and `getRandNum_New()` that generated a random number between 0 and 5 inclusive using `std::rand()` and `std::mt19937`+`std::uniform_int_distribution` respectively.
2. Then I generated 960,000 (divisible by 6) random numbers using the "old" way and recorded the frequencies of the numbers 0-5. Then I calculated the standard deviation of these frequencies. What I'm looking for is a standard deviation as low as possible since that is what would happen if the distribution were truly uniform.
3. I ran that simulation 1000 times and recorded the standard deviation for each simulation. I also recorded the time it took in milliseconds.
4. Afterwards, I did the exact same again but this time generating random numbers the "new" way.
5. Finally, I calculated the mean and standard deviation of the list of standard deviations for both the old and new way and the mean and standard deviation for the list of times taken for both the old and new way.

Here were the results:

```
[OLD WAY]
Spread
       mean:  346.554406
    std dev:  110.318361
Time Taken (ms)
       mean:  6.662910
    std dev:  0.366301

[NEW WAY]
Spread
       mean:  350.346792
    std dev:  110.449190
Time Taken (ms)
       mean:  28.053907
    std dev:  0.654964
```

Surprisingly, the aggregate spread of rolls was the same for both methods. I.e., `std::mt19937`+`std::uniform_int_distribution` was not "more uniform" than simple `std::rand()`+`%`. Another observation I made was that the new was about 4x slower than the old way. Overall, it seemed like I was paying a huge cost in speed for almost no gain in quality.

Is my experiment flawed in some way? Or is `std::rand()` really not that bad, and maybe even better?

For reference, here is the code I used in its entirety:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

int getRandNum_Old() {
    static bool init = false;
    if (!init) {
        std::srand(time(nullptr)); // Seed std::rand
        init = true;
    }

    return std::rand() % 6;
}

int getRandNum_New() {
    static bool init = false;
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 eng;
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,5);
    if (!init) {
        eng.seed(rd()); // Seed random engine
        init = true;
    }

    return dist(eng);
}

template <typename T>
double mean(T* data, int n) {
    double m = 0;
    std::for_each(data, data+n, [&](T x){ m += x; });
    m /= n;
    return m;
}

template <typename T>
double stdDev(T* data, int n) {
    double m = mean(data, n);
    double sd = 0.0;
    std::for_each(data, data+n, [&](T x){ sd += ((x-m) * (x-m)); });
    sd /= n;
    sd = sqrt(sd);
    return sd;
}

int main() {
    const int N = 960000; // Number of trials
    const int M = 1000;   // Number of simulations
    const int D = 6;      // Num sides on die

    /* Do the things the "old" way (blech) */

    int freqList_Old[D];
    double stdDevList_Old[M];
    double timeTakenList_Old[M];

    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::fill_n(freqList_Old, D, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int roll = getRandNum_Old();
            freqList_Old[roll] += 1;
        }
        stdDevList_Old[j] = stdDev(freqList_Old, D);
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto dur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start);
        double timeTaken = dur.count() / 1000.0;
        timeTakenList_Old[j] = timeTaken;
    }

    /* Do the things the cool new way! */

    int freqList_New[D];
    double stdDevList_New[M];
    double timeTakenList_New[M];

    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::fill_n(freqList_New, D, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int roll = getRandNum_New();
            freqList_New[roll] += 1;
        }
        stdDevList_New[j] = stdDev(freqList_New, D);
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto dur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start);
        double timeTaken = dur.count() / 1000.0;
        timeTakenList_New[j] = timeTaken;
    }

    /* Display Results */

    printf("[OLD WAY]\n");
    printf("Spread\n");
    printf("       mean:  %.6f\n", mean(stdDevList_Old, M));
    printf("    std dev:  %.6f\n", stdDev(stdDevList_Old, M));
    printf("Time Taken (ms)\n");
    printf("       mean:  %.6f\n", mean(timeTakenList_Old, M));
    printf("    std dev:  %.6f\n", stdDev(timeTakenList_Old, M));
    printf("\n");
    printf("[NEW WAY]\n");
    printf("Spread\n");
    printf("       mean:  %.6f\n", mean(stdDevList_New, M));
    printf("    std dev:  %.6f\n", stdDev(stdDevList_New, M));
    printf("Time Taken (ms)\n");
    printf("       mean:  %.6f\n", mean(timeTakenList_New, M));
    printf("    std dev:  %.6f\n", stdDev(timeTakenList_New, M));
}
```

Comment: Try to use `getRandNum_Old` in a multi-threaded code. By the way, your both function are inefficient, since they test a condition in each call, which you really don't want to if you care about performance.

Comment: I could simulate you results with some very non-random numbers. You need to look at avalanche properties as well.

Comment: @doron what does simulating with non-random numbers mean? like a deterministic seed?

Comment: That is pretty much why this advice exists.  If you don't know how to test the RNG for sufficient entropy or whether or not it matters for your program then you should assume that std::rand() isn't good enough.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(computing)

Comment: The bottom line on whether `rand()` is good-enough depends largely on what you are using the collection of random numbers for. It you need a particular type of random distribution, then, of course the library implementation will be better. If you simply need random numbers and don't care about the "randomness" or what type of distribution is produced, then `rand()` is fine. Match the proper tool to the job at hand.

Comment: @rcplusplus like repeating a sequence of a handful of numbers.

Comment: Diehard tests are used to check random generators. Also look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778718/how-to-test-random-numbers

Comment: 1) it is safer in multi-threading scenarios, like `rand_r`. 2) it offers better generators. Note that `std::default_random_engine` can be horribly biased (I had to explicitly specify mt19937_64 in some simulations), don't expect the new random functions to be miraculously perfect.

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad I just don't want to hammer this one, so I refrain from actually voting.

Comment: Your comparing apples to oranges (mersenne twister to an LCG). Try comparing LCG to LCG (`minstd_rand`).

Comment: `for (i=0; i<k*n; i++) a[i]=i%n;` produces same exact mean and standard deviation as the best RNG out there. If this is good enough for your application, just use this sequence.

Comment: It isn't just the distribution of random numbers for a large sampling that is relevant for how well a pseudo random number generator performs.  It's also the patterns.  For example, a PRNG that generates a number 1 to 6 (both inclusive), that does so merely by doing `(i++ % 6) + 1` will have a decent distribution, but if you looked at the returned values in order will result in a disturbing pattern as far as (coining a word alert!) randomicity is concerned.

Comment: *What I'm looking for is a standard deviation as low as possible since that is what would happen if the distribution were truly uniform*. We want *truly randomly drawn form uniform* and that doesn't have minimum standard dev..

Comment: "standard deviation as low as possible" - no.  That's wrong.  You *expect* the frequencies to be a little bit different - about sqrt(frequency) is about what you expect the standard deviation to be.  The "incrementing counter" that n.m. produced will have a much lower s.d. (and is a *very* bad rng).

Comment: [Cross-posted on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/9sb3rj/is_random_really_better_than_stdrand/), and there are some good answers there.

Comment: @KonradRudolph cross posted by me actually ;) sorry if that's bad practice...

Comment: An interesting question for programmers, but maybe would have been better asked on https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Do some people really use mod with a random number generator?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - Some do. Should they not?

Comment: if this was my question it would have been put on hold due to being an "opinion" rather than a fact-based question. Cheers to you mate for making it past the troll bridge.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Pretty much any implementation of "old" `rand()` use an [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator); while they are generally not the best generators around, usually you are not going to see them fail on such a basic test - mean and standard deviation is generally got right even by the worst PRNGs.

Common failings of "bad" - but common enough - `rand()` implementations are:

- low randomness of low-order bits;
- short period;
- low `RAND_MAX`;
- some correlation between successive extractions (in general, LCGs produce numbers that are on a limited number of hyperplanes, although this can be somehow mitigated).

Still, none of these are specific to the API of `rand()`. A particular implementation could place a xorshift-family generator behind `srand`/`rand` and, algoritmically speaking, obtain a state of the art PRNG with no changes of interface, so no test like the one you did would show any weakness in the output.

***Edit:** *@R.* correctly notes that the `rand`/`srand` interface is limited by the fact that `srand` takes an `unsigned int`, so any generator an implementation may put behind them is intrinsically limited to `UINT_MAX` possible starting seeds (and thus generated sequences). This is true indeed, although the API could be trivially extended to make `srand` take an `unsigned long long`, or adding a separate `srand(unsigned char *, size_t)` overload.*

---

Indeed, the actual problem with `rand()` is not much of implementation *in principle* but:

- backwards compatibility; many current implementations use suboptimal generators, typically with badly chosen parameters; a notorious example is Visual C++, which sports a `RAND_MAX` of just 32767. However, this cannot be changed easily, as it would break compatibility with the past - people using `srand` with a fixed seed for reproducible simulations wouldn't be too happy (indeed, IIRC the aforementioned implementation goes back to Microsoft C early versions - or even Lattice C - from the mid-eighties);
- simplistic interface; `rand()` provides a single generator with the global state for the whole program. While this is perfectly fine (and actually quite handy) for many simple use cases, it poses problems:

  - with multithreaded code: to fix it you either need a global mutex - which would slow down everything for no reason *and* kill any chance of repeatability, as the sequence of calls becomes random itself -, or thread-local state; this last one has been adopted by several implementations (notably Visual C++);
  - if you want a "private", reproducible sequence into a specific module of your program that doesn't impact the global state.

Finally, the `rand` state of affairs:

- doesn't specify an actual implementation (the C standard provides just a sample implementation), so any program that is intended to produce reproducible output (or expect a PRNG of some known quality) across different compilers must roll its own generator;
- doesn't provide any cross-platform method to obtain a decent seed (`time(NULL)` is not, as it isn't granular enough, and often - think embedded devices with no RTC - not even random enough).

Hence the new `<random>` header, which tries to fix this mess providing algorithms that are:

- fully specified (so you can have cross-compiler reproducible output and guaranteed characteristics - say, range of the generator);
- generally of state-of-the-art quality (*from when the library was designed*; see below);
- encapsulated in classes (so no global state is forced upon you, which avoids completely threading and nonlocality problems);

... and a default `random_device` as well to seed them.

Now, if you ask me I would have liked *also* a simple API built on top of this for the "easy", "guess a number" cases (similar to how Python does provide the "complicated" API, but also the trivial `random.randint` & Co. using a global, pre-seeded PRNG for us uncomplicated people who'd like not to drown in random devices/engines/adapters/whatever every time we want to extract a number for the bingo cards), but it's true that you can easily build it by yourself over the current facilities (while building the "full" API over a simplistic one wouldn't be possible).

---

Finally, to get back to your performance comparison: as others have specified, you are comparing a fast LCG with a slower (but generally considered better quality) Mersenne Twister; if you are ok with the quality of an LCG, you can use `std::minstd_rand` instead of `std::mt19937`.

Indeed, after tweaking your function to use `std::minstd_rand` and avoid useless static variables for initialization

```
int getRandNum_New() {
    static std::minstd_rand eng{std::random_device{}()};
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{0, 5};
    return dist(eng);
}
```

I get 9 ms (old) vs 21 ms (new); finally, if I get rid of `dist` (which, compared to the classic modulo operator, handles the distribution skew for output range not multiple of the input range) and get back to what you are doing in `getRandNum_Old()`

```
int getRandNum_New() {
    static std::minstd_rand eng{std::random_device{}()};
    return eng() % 6;
}
```

I get it down to 6 ms (so, 30% faster), probably because, unlike the call to `rand()`, `std::minstd_rand` is easier to inline.

---

Incidentally, I did the same test using a hand-rolled (but pretty much conforming to the standard library interface) `XorShift64*`, and it's 2.3 times faster than `rand()` (3.68 ms vs 8.61 ms); given that, unlike the Mersenne Twister and the various provided LCGs, it [passes the current randomness test suites with flying colors](http://www.pcg-random.org/statistical-tests.html#testu01-s-crush-and-bigcrush-batteries) *and* it's blazingly fast, it makes you wonder why it isn't included in the standard library yet.

Comment: It's exactly the combination of `srand` and an unspecified algorithm that gets `std::rand`  in trouble.  See also [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad/52881465#52881465).

Comment: `rand` is fundamentally limited at the API level in that the seed (and thus the number of possible sequences that can be produced) is bounded by `UINT_MAX+1`.

Comment: @R..: yep, that's a valid concern I didn't think about - although, `srand` could be trivially upgraded to `unsigned long long` or, adding an overload, to any number of bits.

Comment: just a note: minstd is a bad PRNG, mt19973 is better but not by much: http://www.pcg-random.org/statistical-tests.html#testu01-s-crush-and-bigcrush-batteries (in that chart, minstd==LCG32/64). it's quite a shame that C++ doesn't provide any high-quality, fast, PRNGs like PCG or xoroshiro128+.

Comment: @user60561: indeed I'm appalled that there's no engine of the XorShift family in the standard library - XorShift64* is my go-to engine for pretty much anything nowadays, it's blazingly fast, passes randomness tests with flying colors and it's three lines of code to write. When raw speed is needed XorShift32 is better than most LCGs, faster and has constants (13, 17, 15, compare with the horrible numbers of minstd) that are way easier to remember.

Comment: Don't modern implementations of rand and srand use thread local storage for the shared state?

Comment: @doron: of the implementations I used, only the VC++ CRT does that. glibc has thread-unsafe `rand` but provides `rand_r` (a version with explicit state). BTW IIRC the VC++ TLS version requires you to seed each thread separately, so you must be careful if you start many threads expecting the RNGs to be a "fork" of the current state of `srand`.

Comment: Thanks Matteo :-)

Comment: Good answer. And I agree that a simple, default facade for these facilities would be nice. Indeed, even Bjarne Stroustrup called the `<random>` machinery, "what every random number generator library wants to be when it grows up." See his [keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fX2W3nNjJIo) from CppCon 2017.

Comment: @ravnsgaard: the problem with this approach, as a friend of mine once put it, is that this is a library by and for people who care deeply about random numbers, while 99% of us couldn't care less, we just want to make our bingo cards without much fuss. It's nice that it gives maximum choice and flexibility for the grown-ups, but think also about us little people! That's the same defect of `<chrono>`, FWIW. Honestly I couldn't care less about `std::ratio` and 15 different clocks and `duration_cast`, give me an easy way to get seconds since epoch as `double` and I'll be covered for 99% use cases.

Comment: @MatteoItalia We're not in disagreement. This was also Bjarne's point. We really want `<random>` in the standard, but we would also like a "just give me a decent implementation that I can use now" option. For PRNGs as well as other things.

Comment: @ravnsgaard: yes of course, I was just reinforcing your point :-) Sorry, re-reading it I see that the tone could seem antagonistic.

Comment: A couple notes: 1. Replacing `std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{0, 5}(eng);` with `eng() % 6` reintroduces the skew factor that the `std::rand` code suffers from (admittedly minor skew in this case, where the engine has `2**31 - 1` outputs, and you're distributing them to 6 buckets). 2. On your note about "`srand` takes an `unsigned int`" which limits the possible outputs, as written, seeding your engine with just `std::random_device{}()` has the same problem; [you need a `seed_seq` to properly initialize most PRNGs](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/109266/118085).

Comment: To be clear, I understand that using `std::random_device{}()` for the seed is fine for `std::minstd_rand` (which only has a `uint_fast32_t` of state, and thus will be limited to `2**32` possible output streams), and is fine for simple illustration (where you're just trying to match `std::rand`, not improve on it), I just wanted to make it clear that in the general case, for higher quality PRNGs with greater state size, failing to fully initialize them means you lose the breadth of possible outputs, and render yourself more predictable than you might like to be.

Comment: I was under the impression that Mersenne Twister is _faster_ than LCG. Back in the days I remember switching LCG out for MT mainly for that reason and only secondarily for its better randomness properties. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Chortos-2: I'd be surprised to see the MT faster than an LCG with decent parameters; although numbers are essentially generated in batches, so the complicated part runs once in a while, still MT is a significantly more complicated algorithm (with branches!) and with big state. An LCG instead has just multiplication as "costly" part - if the modulo is chosen adequately (as in minstd_rand) [no costly modulo operation is actually performed](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/haIct0).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: It's possible I'm making some mistake, but I wrote a stupid tester a while ago that tested generating random bytes from different engines (used exact same code, only the `using` statement changed which engine to build off of, and the bytes read at a time was keyed to the engine's `result_type`'s size). Compiled identically (including `-march=native`, which mattered for MT, but not the LCG), populating 1M bytes, `std::minstd_rand0` took around 2.4 ms, vs. 0.9 ms for mt19937 and 0.5 ms for mt19937_64. MT64 is asked for half as many outputs, but even MT beat `std::minstd_rand0`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger that's interesting for sure, I'll check again on several machines. Maybe it's possible that with new instruction sets parts of the algorithm got faster?

Comment: [This is the core of the code](https://tio.run/##lVHRTsIwFH3nK/oi6YAJiqgw4Bf8AGOaUsq8ydYu7R0RCb/uvCuQiRGCfViX3nPuPedcVRRxqlRV9fulB5MyJ83S5kKbFIxmM@ZxOZnkYOgWdW2QtC4B8W48Hj6Jx4ek1fIoEdQvYKrNdrBrqmsLywARhS3KTKLmodNaK7RuWoLBZ4HzdsBEbNtidJQlPczDpxbITJkvNqg9aagxt/Uzj5IAPJk9mTjtywwFbgrNOvsmNcJIrMmaZmlXOI1CSY/T8@TOnLc7QeZCU5EHbTQyzAzvpYGVdbmglmIJHh0sSgRrLjSdMwJuA5ssaQdKZJAD@kucsBse9dj/efKDR7t9TCSV8UOcwGaDhL7TJth@iNqu@PmGUcK6XTju5xg9BfsKb5QtOeO0@cNWdtcEddw887nMsjqaQY/dj0Z/S27Exs3vzVW6f1r908XewlHGiY9dVX2pVSZTX8WrDG0VvwyrOJdOvc/IPKz1Nw); the `main` just makes a 1M byte `vector` & populates it 10 times.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: The rest of the code is basically just includes, and using `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` to time it. In my original code, I also seeded the engine from `std::random_device`, short code uses fixed seed, but performance is roughly the same either way.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I made [a way simplified version](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/mitalia/AeRgqo) to exclude any "distracting factor" from the test; the result is interesting: without `-march=native`, I get 4.95 s for rand0 and 7.11 s for MT, but enabling `-march=native` makes MT go down to 2.21s (while rand0 stays the same)! So, it seems indeed that new instruction sets did provide useful stuff for the codegen of the MT.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I just remembered why mine behaved the way it did; it was using a distribution with a range based on the underlying type, but `rand0` doesn't actually produce the full range of its underlying type, which means the distribution must pull more than one value to fill the underlying type, and have bit mixing and (rarely taken) branches to prevent biased output; MT/MT64 generate the full range, so the distribution doesn't have to do any massaging to ensure unbiased outputs, making it roughly a no-op. Basically, MT/MT64 likely win whenever you need power of 2 ranges (including bytes).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Reading up more, it seems that LCG with a power-of-two modulus is faster than MT (and anything else for that matter) but minstd is slower, so what I remembered was true but applied only to minstd in particular rather than all LCG. Sources: [1.1](http://www.pcg-random.org/rng-performance.html), [1.2](http://www.pcg-random.org/other-rngs.html), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32027839/865331), [3, on Matsumoto’s MT home page](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/ewhat-is-mt.html) (I suspect it refers to Linux `rand` now being an alias for `random`, which isn’t LCG).

Comment: And I do distinctly remember speed being a factor 10 or 11 years ago, although to be fair I can’t say whether I did my own tests or only read about it. Meanwhile, on my 8-year-old machine, running OP’s code with all initialization moved to file-scope static variables and with `% 6` everywhere, compiled with GCC 6, shows that `std::mt19937` is faster than `std::minstd_rand` by about 10% without LTO, with or without `-march=native`, and by 17% with LTO. (And PGO actually slowed down minstd for some reason, so I’ll disregard that.)

Comment: Apparently, there are [optimized MT implementations](https://github.com/cslarsen/mersenne-twister) as well. I’ve also considered that `% 6` together with inlining might be benefiting the LCG, so I’ve run a test with the `getRandNum` functions moved to a separate file and without LTO: 17% faster. All in all, I think OP’s performance results are not due to MT being slower but due to an unfair comparison involving static initialization within the function and `uniform_int_distribution`.

Answer (score 7):

If you repeat your experiment with a range larger than 5 then you will probably see different results. When your range is significantly smaller than `RAND_MAX` there isn't an issue for most applications.

For example if we have a `RAND_MAX` of 25 then `rand() % 5` will produce numbers with the following frequencies:

```
0: 6
1: 5
2: 5
3: 5
4: 5
```

As `RAND_MAX` is guaranteed to be more than 32767 and the difference in frequencies between the least likely and the most likely is only 1, for small numbers the distribution is near enough random for most use cases.

Comment: This is explained in STL's second slide

Comment: Ok, but... who is STL ? And what slides ? (serious question)

Comment: @kebs, Stephan Lavavej, see the Youtube reference in the question.

Answer (score 3):

First, surprisingly, the answer changes depending on what you are using the random number for. If it is to drive, say, a random background color changer, using rand() is perfectly fine. If you are using a random number to create a random poker hand or a cryptographically secure key, then it is not fine.

Predictability: the sequence 012345012345012345012345... would provide an even distribution of each number in your sample, but obviously isn't random. For a sequence to be random, the value of n+1 cannot be easily predicted by the value of n (or even by the values of n, n-1, n-2, n-3, etc.) Clearly a repeating sequence of the same digits is a degenerate case, but a sequence generated with any linear congruential generator can be subjected to analysis; if you use default out-of-the-box settings of a common LCG from a common library, a malicious person could "break the sequence" without much effort at all. In the past, several on-line casinos (and some brick-and-mortar ones) were hit for losses by machines using poor random number generators. Even people who should know better have been caught up; TPM chips from several manufacturers have been demonstrated to be easier to break than the bit-length of the keys would otherwise predict because of poor choices made with key-generation parameters.

Distribution: As alluded to in the video, taking a modulo of 100 (or any value not evenly divisible into the length of the sequence) will guarantee that some outcomes will become at least slightly more likely than other outcomes. In the universe of 32767 possible starting values modulo 100, the numbers 0 through 66 will appear 328/327 (0.3%) more often than the values 67 through 99; a factor that may provide an attacker an advantage.

Comment: "Predictability: the sequence 012345012345012345012345... would pass your test for "randomness", in that there would be an even distribution of each number in your sample" actually, not really; what he is measuring is the stddev _of the stddevs_ between runs, i.e. essentially how the various runs histogram are spread out. With a 012345012345012345... generator it would always be zero.

Comment: Good point; I read through OP's code a bit too quickly, I'm afraid. Edited my answer to reflect.

Comment: Hehe I know because I though to make that test as well, and I noticed I obtained different results 

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is: it depends on what you mean by "better."

The "new" `<random>` engines were introduced to C++ over 13 years ago, so they're not really new.  The C library `rand()` was introduced decades ago and has been very useful in that time for any number of things.

The C++ standard library provides three classes of random number generator engines: the Linear Congruential (of which `rand()` is an example), the Lagged Fibonacci, and the Mersenne Twister.  There are tradeoffs of each class, and each class is "best" in certain ways.  For example, the LCGs have very small state and if the right parameters are chosen, fairly fast on modern desktop processors.  The LFGs have larger state and use only memory fetches and addition operation, so are very fast on embedded systems and microcontrollers that lack specialized math hardware. The MTG has huge state and is slow, but can have a very large non-repeating sequence with excellent spectral characteristics.

If none of the supplied generators are good enough for your specific use, the C++ standard library also provides an interface for either a hardware generator or your own custom engine.  None of the generators are intended to be used standalone: their intended use is through a distribution object that provides a random sequence with a particular probability distribution function.

Another advantage of `<random>` over `rand()` is that `rand()` uses global state, is not reentrant or threadsafe, and allows a single instance per process.  If you need fine-grained control or predictability (ie. able to reproduce a bug given the RNG seed state) then `rand()` is useless.  The `<random>` generators are locally instanced and have serializable (and restorable) state.