# Word Guessing Game C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming, so I created number guessing game which worked perfectly but I can't seem to finish with the word guessing code. My goal is to print "Congratulations" when the guessed string is correct, but I tried many ways and I still can't make it work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int i;
    const string wordList[17] = { "television",
        "computer", "keyboard", "laptop", "mouse", "phone", "headphones",
        "screen", "camera", "sound", "science", "programming", 
        "entertainment",
        "graphics", "intelligent", "memory", "remote" };

    string word = wordList[rand() % 17];

    for(i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        if(word[i] == 'a' || word[i] == 'e' || word[i] == 'i' ||
           word[i] == 'o' || word[i] == 'u')
        {
            word[i] = '_';
        }
    }

    cout << word << endl;
    int n=0;
    string x;
    do
    {
        n++;
        cin >> x;
    }
    while(x!=word[i]);
    cout<<"Congratulations! You guessed the word!";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What, **exactly**, about the shown code, doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Think about the characters that are contained in `word`. What happened to all the vowels? And do you compare 2 `string`s?

Comment: Also, when you're comparing the most recent character to `word[i]`, where does `i` come from?

Comment: Your compiler should be giving you an error for `while(x!=word[i])`

Comment: so i used  `char x` instead of  `string x` now it compiles but when i input the correct word still repeats even tho its correct

Comment: `word` is the string modified (vowels -> '_'), you need to compare the user input with the unmodified source.

Comment: so i declared one more string called `guess` which is most recent `word` but i cant fix the code `while(x!=guess)` so that it would print accordingly to the input

Comment: i fixed it! thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are u replacing vowels with _?

Comment: @HelpingBean: It's a guessing game. Here's a word with all vowels blanked out, guess what it is.

Comment: Did you intend to limit the number of guesses? What's `n` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say most of your problems come down to this line:

```
while(x!=word[i]);
```

As the comments suggest, `word` is your modified word, not the word list. But also, `i` is the wrong index. So save the word index you chose earlier:

```
size_t wordIndex = rand() % 17;
string word = wordList[wordIndex];
```

Then change your `do` loop condition:

```
while (x != wordList[wordIndex]);
```

I'd also recommend that you [don't use `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10077).

You could [argue about the use of `rand()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53040940/10077), but it might not be worth it. Just be aware that `rand()` has shortcomings and better alternatives exist.