# Trying to Generate Random Numbers in a Specific Range in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I am trying to generate a list of 10 randomly generated numbers in the range of 100000 to 583662 and every thing I have tried results in all numbers beginning with a 1 and no numbers higher than 199999 are ever generated.  I have actually generated 1000 numbers to see if maybe it was just too small of a sample, but in 1000 numbers I should have had at least a few numbers higher than 199999, but none were.  Here is the code I hae been using for this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>
    #define SIZE 100

    int main()
    {
        int globalArray[SIZE] = {0};
        srand((unsigned)time(0));
        int count;
        for (int count = 0; count < 100; ++count) {
            globalArray[count] = (rand() % 483662) + 100000;
        }
        for (int count = 0; count < 100; ++count) {
            printf("%d\n", globalArray[count]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The `random` header has what you need to do this.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why you don't use `rand`. `RAND_MAX` can be as small as 32767.

Comment: Related: [Why is the new random library better than std::rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53040940/9716597)

Comment: @BessieTheCow So what other function can be used to generate the range of random numbers I am looking for?

Comment: Stuff in the C++ [`<random>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random), such as [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) with a properly seeded generator.

Comment: An entertaining and educational presentation on just how much worse than the modern alternatives `rand` is: [Rand Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new `<random>` library instead of `std::rand` and improve the readability of your code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 engine{std::random_device{}()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution dist{100000, 583662}; // inclusive

    std::generate_n(std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, "\n"}, 1000,
                    [&] { return dist(engine); });
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/s4gHuNwPFpjINOJn))

---

To generate the numbers into an array, per comment:

```
std::generate_n(globalArray, SIZE, [&] { return dist(engine); });
```

or:

```
std::generate(std::begin(globalArray), std::end(globalArray), [&] { return dist(engine); });
```

Even simpler with C++20 ranges or ranges-v3:

```
namespace ranges = std::ranges; // C++20
ranges::generate(globalArray, [&] { return dist(engine); });
```

Comment: How do i incorporate this into my array to generate the 10 numbers I am needing?

Comment: You have a wide number of distributions to choose from, e.g. [Pseudo-random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use:

```
rand() / (float)RAND_MAX * range
```

From, platform to platform, RAND_MAX varies. If your RAND_MAX is smaller than 483662, you won't get the full range.

An alternative would be:

```
(rand() + rand() * RAND_MAX) % range
```

Comment: That just hides the underlying problem of `rand` not generating enough entropy. You'll get numbers which are spread out but only a fraction of the numbers in the range can be generated.

Comment: good point. Might still be useful, depends on the domain where the numbers are used.