# random.random() and random.seed() python funcs in c++?

Tags: c++, random

what is the c++ Version of this python code?
I want to have a special random number according to a Special number in a loop.
python Version:

```
import random 
nextRTSeed = 0;
while(True):
    nextRTSeed+=1
    random.seed(nextRTSeed)
    print( "rand ------->>   ", (random.random()) )
    if(nextRTSeed>10):
        break
```

1. rand ------->>    0.13436424411240122
2. rand ------->>    0.9560342718892494
3. rand ------->>    0.23796462709189137
4. rand ------->>    0.23604808973743452
5. ...

Comment: Is there a specification of what algorithm the python random number generator uses?   If not, there is no solution to your question.

Comment: @Peter Afaik, Python uses the Mersenne Twister internally. I'm not sure with which constants it uses it though.

Comment: @mahmoodhasanzadeh When you asked this question, did you have a "correct" answer in mind?

Answer (score 1):

A direct translation would probably look like this:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(17);  // we want many decimals   
 
    std::mt19937 random;                                     // A PRNG
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0., 1.);     // distribution [0,1)

    for(int nextRTSeed = 1; nextRTSeed <= 11; ++nextRTSeed) {
        random.seed(nextRTSeed);                             // reseeding the PRNG
        std::cout << dist(random) << '\n';                   // print random number
    }
}
```

Note: Reseeding your PRNG (pseudo random number generator) is rarely needed. You should usually only seed it *once* and then just keep calling it. Like this:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(17);    
    
    std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());           // A seeded PRNG    
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0., 1.);

    for(int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
        std::cout << dist(prng) << '\n';
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MzPqEMsno)

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you will get a random number in C++

```cpp
#include <iostream> // For input/output
#include <cstdlib> // for rand() and srand()

int main()
{
    int maxRandValue = 100
    srand(time(null)); // Sets seed of random to time now.
    std::cout << "The random number is: "<< rand() % maxRandValue; // Range: 0 - 100
}
```

*NOTE* the rand() function in Python/C++ is not random but pseudo-random for more see this video: https://youtu.be/Nm8NF9i9vsQ

Bye!

Comment: You are missing `<ctime>` for the `time()` function. Also `rand()` and `srand()` are highly discouraged in C++. Instead, use the `<random>` library.

Comment: Ok. I am making a library about that is supposed to be the equivalent of python libraries.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I am just asking but why is rand() and srand() discouraged?

Comment: You can read [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040940/why-is-the-new-random-library-better-than-stdrand)

Comment: Also read [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad)